# C# Wait for serial transmission to complete

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'd like to wait for a serial transmission to complete before proceeding with reading bytes from it. (I have a half duplex line and do not want to receive my own transmission.)

I have tried:

```
serial.Write("Stuff to write");
while (serial.BytesToWrite > 0)
{
    continue; // Wait till all bytes gone.
}
serial.DiscardInBuffer(); // Clear received half duplex reflection.
```

but this is not working; the reflection is received. Seems BytesToWrite  returns 0 immediately.

An equivalent in VB does work.

Is there some other way to wait for the transmission to complete?

Comment: Echoing back the data sent by a certain program is a function of the program of the communication partner, and cannot be dealt with by using the API on the sending side. If it can be stopped by sending a configuration setting or command to stop echo back to the communication partner, specify it. If there is no such function, create a program on the assumption that the transmitted data will be echoed back.

Comment: I have worked around it exactly like this for the moment but it's rather inelegant. With VB I've found BytesToWrite a dependable metric for determining if the transmit is done, not so with C#.

Comment: If you really want to detect the completion of transmission on Windows, you can create your own library using Win32API with C++/CLI instead of SerialPort of .NET and detect EV_TXEMPTY. [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o), [SetCommMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommmask), [WaitCommEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-waitcommevent)

Comment: *"Is there some other way to wait for the transmission to complete?"* -- That cannot be done reliably from userspace.  Only the device driver can accurately determine when transmission is complete.  Is this RS-485?  A hardware solution is possible by using a transceiver that suppresses echo.

Comment: For example, such a device. Switch pin #2 of [RS422/485 to USB Serial Adapter Cable](https://antaira.eu/file/11255/_.pdf), Dip switch SW-B SW1 of [USB ⇔ RS-422/485 Interface ConverterSI-35USB SI-35USB-2](http://www.lineeye.com/html/p_SI-35USB.html)

Comment: No not RS485; it's a 1 wire interface I made myself where an open collector at each end pulls down a single line during active bits.

Comment: I am shocked BytesToWrite  would behave differently with VB and C# ?